# dynamic CAML query in DataView web part

Tags: data-view-web-part, caml-query

I need to generate a dynamic CAML query for DataView web part. My requirement is similar to what is mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985560/sharepoint-dynamic-caml-query-problem .

I'm trying to use following Query:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <In>
            <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
            <Values>
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($IDs, ',')">
                    <Value Type="Text"><xsl:value-of select="."/></Value>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Values>
        </In>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

But I'm not able to use `xsl:for-each` in CAML query. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

XSLT code can be used only inside `<Xsl>` tag of DVWP. `<Query>` tag can include only CAML elements described in following MSDN article:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx

There is no way to create a dynamic CAML query using xslt. You can create it either programmatically (from other webpart on same page or by creating a DataViewWebPart descendant), or you can use parameters (from `<ParametersBindings>`, like this: `{nameOfParameter}`) - but the latter approach is rather limited and I'm afraid it couldn't be used in your particular situation, because there is no way to split a parameter into pieces using CAML.

Comment: Can I set value of parameterbinding using JS code / connected webpart?

Comment: Connected webpart - yes. Also ParameterBindings can be automatically gathered from server controls, form inputs, query string, etc. - depending of Location attribute. But you will be able to use the parameter value only in a limited way, due to CAML query schema limitedness.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll check how to connect a custom web part with DataView web part. If you have any reference related to this can you please share?

Comment: I don't, but I anticipate you will need to use `SPLimitedWebPartManager` to find the DVWP on the page where your custom webpart is placed.